# Extracting Data from a .txt file using python

Tags: python, xml, text, extract

I many, many .xml files and i need to extract some co-ordinates from them. 
Extracting data straight from .xml files seems to be very, very complicated - so i am working saving the .xml files as .txt files and extracting the data that way. However, when i open the .txt file, my data is all bunched together on about 6 lines.. And all the scripts i have found so far select the data by reading the first word on each line.. but obviously that won't work for me! 
I need to extract the numbers inbetween these comments:

```
<gml:lowerCorner>137796 483752</gml:lowerCorner> <gml:upperCorner>138178 484222</gml:upperCorner>
```

In the text file they are all grouped together! Does anyone know how to extract this data? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think it will be easier to extract the data if you call the file ".txt" rather than ".xml", seeing as the contents are exactly the same?

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html ? Python can easily parse XML.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is absolutely the **wrong approach**. Leave it alone and improve your ways :-)

Seriously, if the file is XML, then just use an XML parser to read it. Learning how to do it in Python isn't hard and will make your life easier now and much easier in the future, when you may find yourself facing more complex parsing needs, and you won't have to re-learn it.

Look at `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree`. Here's some sample code:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
>>> tree = ElementTree()
>>> tree.parse("your_xml_file.xml")
```

Now just read the documentation of the module and see what you can do with `tree`. You'll be surprised to find out how simple it is to get to information this way. If you have specific questions about extracting data, I suggest you open another question in which you specify the format of the XML file you have to parse, and what data you have to take out of there. I'm sure you will have working code suggested to you in matters of minutes.

Comment: +1 for: *Seriously, if the file is XML, then just use an XML parser to read it.*

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add at the beginning of my question - "I am new to python - ive only ever made one script in my life!!" I will look into this whole parsing business! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Alice Duff: sure thing, this is what SO is for, and then the first sentence of my answer is especially important for you :)

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: Excuse me, Mister, I don’t agree with you, I don’t think that there are absolute solutions in the field of programming. I have no time to develop, just to say that if there are several possibilities to solve a problem, they must be comparatively examined. Acceptability of a solution depends on the criteria that are accepted at the beginning. Excuse my poor skill in english.

Comment: @eyquem: it's perfectly alright to disagree. As in any SO answer/discussion, I'm just expression *my opinion* here. Yours may differ. I still think I gave the OP a good advice, especially considering it's a newbie we're talking about

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: Excuse me but I don’t see any relative opinion in the sentence “This is absolutely the wrong approach.“ I just understand it as the expression of an absolute truth.

Comment: @eyquem: and still I should insist that everything I (and probably others as well) say here should be implicitly prefixed with a big, blinking IMHO :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also open through the python script .xml file as you open a .txt file.

```
    data = open("file.xml")
    xml = data.read()
```

Then you can use regular expressions to find those numbers you want so badly.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer is still the top answer.  However, I've been doing just this with HTML and this link [lxml and xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) ideal.

Open your browser to the site (or data) which is of interest.  In Chrome, right click and 'Inspect Element'.  In the Developer window on the highlighted text right click again and 'Copy XPath'.  For google.com and clicking on the main search box I get the following XPath.

```
//*[@id="lst-ib"]
```

You can use lxml to grab various data from this item.  See what you get when you append 'text()' or '@value' or '@href' on the end.

Answer (score -2):

For really simple xml i just use a regex, can't be botherd to start an slow xml parser for a simple xml packet.

```
In [1]: data = open("file.txt","r").read()

In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.compile("([\d]+)").findall(data)
Out[3]: ['137796', '483752', '138178', '484222']
```

Comment: Surely, your regex could be improved. But, on the principle expressed by your answer, I have the same opinion. So I upvoted it. I also think that downvoting answers without the slightest explanation is a wrong practice because it’s unfair and it doesn’t brings possibility to think and meditate about a problem. And now, I will probably be downvoted.